# Vue app automatically changing position of # within URL when clicking on a button link

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a question with vue router. I'm working on a custom library of vue that most of the code has already been created before me. My question has to do with trying to get a page to use a back button on the page that works on a registration process flow (it works on all other pages, besides this one particular page).

I'm not quite sure whats exactly going on with why it's acting a certain way with the '#', which I assume is going to be the problem:

The flow of the app should go like this:

1. http://localhost:8080/#/events, hitting the 'Continue' button goes to the next page (product page)
2. http://localhost:8080/#/product, hitting the 'Continue' button goes to the next page (upgrade page)
3. http://localhost:8080/upgrade#/, hitting the 'Continue' button goes to the next page (payment page)

Each page has a back button on the page to go back to the previous one. Going from '/upgrade#/' and hitting the back button, the app gives me a link to a blank page with this URL:

http://localhost:8080/upgrade#/product

I'm not sure from when we are on the page of:

http://localhost:8080/#/product

and hit the Continue button, why the '#' moves to after '/upgrade'.

This is our method we are using to change pages:

```
changeRoute() {
    this.$router.push("/product");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to put [vue-router mode to history](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode).

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

The default mode for vue-router is hash mode, which is why you are seeing this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Would this mess with any of the other routes, that have already been created in the app that work currently?